# Highlighting the Max value

Tags: r

I have created a data frame that gives me the max value for certain columns I want to see from that day. I want the max value for that column highlighted, what can I use?

Here is the code I used to get the table

```
jump_table <- daily_jump1 %>%
  group_by(athlete, date,load,rep_number) %>%
  summarise(
    daily_max_vel = max(rep_max_vel),
    daily_peak_power = max(rep_peak_power),
    daily_peakmRFD = max(rep_peak_mRFD)
)
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the overall max value per day, get rid of `athlete`, `load`, and `rep_number` abd use `group_by(date)`. If you want the max per day per athlete, use `group_by(athlete, date)`.